# Side by side JSON diff with the npm jsoneditor package

Tags: json, npm, diff, jsoneditor

I'm looking for something like [this](https://jsoneditoronline.org):
[image]

using the [jsoneditor npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsoneditor).

I haven't managed to find any side-by-side compare or "diff" mode in [the API](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/blob/master/docs/api.md).

**Does anyone know if this is already supported in the package?**

**Or of another package they'd recommend which provides the side-by-side diff?**

Otherwise it looks like I'll have to run the json through a separate diff package and based on the output use the underlying ACE editor's highlight API to emulate the jsoneditoronline diff functionality.

Any recommendations on the above points would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Based on this comment - https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/issues/1178
This requires a custom implementation, this link might be a good start: https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/blob/develop/examples/20_custom_css_style_for_nodes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this comment -
https://www.github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/issues/1178
it requires a custom implementation.

This link might be a good start:
https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/blob/develop/examples/20_custom_css_style_for_nodes.html